# What does "npm install -g" stand for?

Tags: npm

What does

```
npm install -g ...
```

stand for? I saw this in a tutorial but I don't know what the -g flag does. Does it install from Github?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It installs it globally and adds it to the path. This is nice for npm packages that are basically just command-line applications, like yarn.

You can always look up options here
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

-g used to install that npm package globally so that their executable components are available in the system PATH

See the docs on the topic of globally installed packages [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally).